# Simple HTML Issue (with Particles.)

Tags: html

I have a page on my server with some "particle" effects, and for some reason, I can't get them to display behind the image without the image disappearing.

Please help me!

Thank you,

William

I can provide code if needed, also here is what I am talking about: (link to screenshot) http://hi.lario.us/ehBB

Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, code is needed.

Comment: Thinking we can solve this without code. You certainly are hilarious. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Move `<div id="particles" class="hidden-xs">` and its contents up straight after `<body>`, and in the `<div>` opening tag, before the closing `>`, add `style="position: absolute;"`.